# Quelle est l'intention impliquée par l'orthographe "Jasus" ?

Tags: orthographe

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* :

> Plus innocentes plus on les hume plus c'est bonheur ! Faut écarteler les **Jasus** !

Je vois que *Jasus* est à comprendre ici pour "Jésus", mais cette altération reste obscure pour moi.

Savez-vous quelle est l'intention impliquée par cette orthographe ?

Answer (score 3):

Un **Jasus** (lalandii)est une langouste, un crustacé que l'on déguste en l'écartelant, en arrachant ses membres.
Céline étant amateur de bonne chère, c'est sans doute sans rapport avec Jésus.

Sous toute réserve car je n'ai pas le livre pour juger du contexte.

Comment: C'est très écartelé par les cheveux... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Il est utile de situer le mot qui est en question plus amplement dans le texte de *Fééries*, et j'ajoute donc d'abord un passage plus volumineux qui le contient.

> Folie, cohue, les mêmes en Grève à l'équarrissage national ! à l'arrachage des yeux de vaincus ! Les grands orgasmes des Prudents ! l'Armée Sade en piquenic d'Histoire ! l'Église que ça va s'édifier dans mettons dix...quinze... vingt ans ! Petiot pape ! L'Europe-la-Goulue !
> – Et le saint Martin, vous le comptez plus ? le saint des Gaules ?... pas le Boulevard ! ni la porte Putaine !
> non ! le saint ! vous en ferez rien ? Repaganisés sans idoles ! que c'est amer ! Fabriquer des rires sur les pals !
> Ah, gardez tout ! Pourtant Féerie ? ma bicyclette ?... Ah, vous auriez autrement ri, godé, là, net fol ! et gratis
> si ils m'avaient traîné place Blanche, disposé vous voyez la grille, en sorte de chapelets de mes viscères, en
> dentelle d'organes... les petits... les gros... vivisecté à l'aiguille devant le Restaurant Duquèquet ! Que mes
> cris auraient retenti des hauts d'Enghien à Port-Royal !... au moins cinq millions de personnes qui
> s'émouvaient prenaient l'amour, des psychanalysés déboutés, frigides au coco, kola, Mayol, martinets,
> urinoirs, croûtons ! tout ! Des désespérés finis !... Je bienfaisais cinq cent mille ménages ! Oh, que j'ai déçu !
> Pas seulement autour, là, la Butte, les glacis, Caulaincourt... Custine... Dufayel !... mais la Grande Banlieue
> et la proche ! J'ai encore des ressentiments, des gens qui m'écrivent de fureur ! *T'es foutu le camp ! voyou ! couard ! gono !*
> Je les ai frustrés de mon pal et scalp ! Ils pardonneront pas !
> Les martyres, les Golgothas, c'est des félicités, des Ciels ! Jamais les bonheurs de familles saccadent mieux,
> s'étreignent l'âme, les fesses, les tétons, et que je te les remords ! remâche les doigts de pied, comme autour
> des boucheries de martyrs ! et plus ça saigne ! foutre ! ruisselle ! le knout là-dessus ! et flac ! et plof ! plus c'est
> aux anges ! plus c'est panouï !
> – Programme, chérie ?
> Ah jouisserie néon ! la folichonnerie totale ! Ah cocotte ! Ah m'aime-moi ! m'aime ! Ah, prends m'en
> tout ! m'enmour ! enmour ! en ! en ! en ! t'en as quatre ! dix ! vingt ! cent ! grosses ! Ah ! Oh ! Hu ! en ! tout !
> Pensez d'Enghien à Marcadet ! les bastions ! Pantin ! le Saint-Michel !... et encore d'autres !... les frères par charrettes ! défilant... les tombereaux de victimes ouvertes ! viscères chauds !... Plus innocentes plus on
> les hume plus c'est bonheur ! Faut écarteler les **Jasus** ! Plus ils déchirent l'air de leurs cris, plus Juliette hoque, vogue, gode, Roméo pousse ! Ces galops de caresses pétries fesses ! charge ! Ah ! mamour ! d'amour !
> enmour ! ton cœur ! feu ! crise ! jus ! Cieux ! ah ! ah ! reste ! fonds ! fonds ! Diable ! chichis !
> – Oh, mais ce drôle nous outrepasse !
> – N'en parlons plus ! mais le fait est tout de même certain, la promesse signée, notariée, fut radiodiffusée
> sur deux cent trente postes ! mes burnes passées à l'heure XU au cou du plus vengeur fureur purateur de la porte d'Alfort au pont de Flandre !... Secteur est : Les Carrières-Goutte-d'Or ! Jugez l'étendue ! ces réseaux !
> Oh, mais ces temps sont terminés ! ces fêtes des cadavres aux égouts ! Je ratiocine ! Ces Saint-Barthélemys sur le pouce, sans carillons, paters, trompettes !
> Maintenant faut un autre genre de rire...

Il est question d'abord des sévices dont été victimes certains caratères historiques.

- *La Révolution continua la tradition : la première exécution par guillotine eut lieu en [place de Grève](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%C3%A9xecutions+en+place+de+gr%C3%A8ve) en 1792. La dernière exécution sur cette place fut celle de Jean-Pierre Martin, condamné à mort pour vol et assassinat et exécuté le 22 juillet 1830.*

L'auteur continue en faisant référence à d'autres sévices, ceux-là soufferts par des personnages  légendaires, et si d'une nature connexe, quand même différents puisqu'il s'agit de ceux découlant de ce que l'on peut appeler la mortification de la chair.

- ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_de_Tours)) *En 371 à Tours, l’évêque en place Lidoire vient de mourir ; les habitants veulent choisir Martin mais celui-ci s’est choisi une autre voie et n’aspire pas à l'épiscopat. Les habitants l’enlèvent donc et le proclament évêque le 4 juillet 371 sans son consentement ; Martin se soumet en pensant qu’il s’agit là sans aucun doute de la volonté divine (un cas identique de contrainte face à un non-consentement se reproduira en 435 pour Eucher de Lyon).  Les autres évêques ne l’aiment guère car il a un aspect pitoyable dû aux mortifications et aux privations excessives qu’il s’inflige, il porte des vêtements rustiques et grossiers.*

Ensuite, il évoque des tortures qui auraient pu lui être infligées, à lui, l'auteur, autant  plus d'atrocités qu'on puisse imaginer dans le lot des horreurs auxquelles  l'humain est sujet.

Il passe à une autre sorte des « souffrances » de la chair, celles que l'on peut trouver dans la sexualité, et il la compare à celles dont les saints ont pu être victimes (recherchée dans un but d'expiation (mortification) ou le résultat de l'adversité  de leurs contemporains), disant d'emblée que cette dernière est vastement supérieure ( « des félicité, des Ciels ! »), mais il en profite néanmoins pour classer certains comportement sexuels dans sa vision de la souffrance de la chair.

- *Les martyres, les Golgothas, c'est des félicités, des Ciels ! Jamais les bonheurs de familles saccadent mieux, s'étreignent l'âme, les fesses, les tétons, et que je te les remords ! remâche les doigts de pied, comme autour des boucheries de martyrs ! et plus ça saigne ! foutre ! ruisselle ! le knout là-dessus ! et flac ! et plof ! plus c'est aux anges ! plus c'est panouï !*

Il reprend le thème des êtres humains exécutés de façon que l'on ne croit jamais pouvoir appeler légitime et que l'on accepte dans le cadre du fait historique, fait que l'on classe en l'occurrence parmi les horreurs de l'histoireil amplifie dans le sens de son thème de la souffrance de la chair (une souffrance qu'il méprise jusqu'à un certain point, assez évidemment, bien qu'il ne soit pas clair que ce soit selon un point de vue particulier, si ce n'est celui de sa propre anxiété face à la souffrance).

- Pensez d'Enghien à Marcadet ! les bastions ! Pantin ! le Saint-Michel !... et encore d'autres !... les frères par charrettes ! défilant... les tombereaux de victimes ouvertes ! viscères chauds !... Plus innocentes plus on les hume plus c'est bonheur ! Faut écarteler les Jasus !

Le jasus est un crustacé au nom plus courant de *[langouste du Cap](https://www.techdico.com/translation/english-french/cape+rock+lobster.html)* (« Cape Rock lobster » en anglais).

- [jasus](https://www.sealifebase.ca/summary/jasus-lalandii.html)  […] The tails of this species are exported frozen in the shell, or peeled and canned.
  Traduction : *Les queues de cette espèce sont exportées congelées dans leur carapaces, ou décortiquées et en conserve.*

L'image « écarteler les jasus » est claire : il est  souvent le cas, dans le but ou le procès de manger des crustacés que l'on arrache les pattes en les décortiquants, soit dans l'assiette, soit à la préparation pour la vente, ou à celle d'un plat.

Jésus dans l'église Chrétienne est associé au plus haut point avec l'idée de la [mortification de la chair](https://stringfixer.com/fr/Instrument_of_penance).

- *La mortification de la chair est un acte par lequel un individu ou un groupe cherche à mortifier, ou à mettre à mort, sa nature pécheresse , dans le cadre du processus de sanctification.  La mortification de la chair est entreprise pour se repentir des péchés et participer à la Passion de Jésus.  Dans le christianisme, les formes courantes de mortification qui sont pratiquées à ce jour incluent le jeûne, l' abstinence, ainsi que l' agenouillement pieux.  Autrefois commun parmi les ordres religieux chrétiens dans le passé, le port du sac, ainsi queflagellation à l'imitation des souffrances et de la mort par crucifixion de Jésus de Nazareth.*

En considération  de ce que Jésus représente dans la Bible, il n'y a aucun doute : Céline a vu l'opportunité d'une image « juteuse », et il s'est laissé aller encore une fois à l'une de ses passions favorite, c'est à dire rire.

- pas le Boulevard ! ni la porte Putaine ! non ! le saint ! vous en ferez rien ? Repaganisés sans idoles ! que c'est amer ! Fabriquer des rires sur les pals ! Ah, gardez tout ! Pourtant Féerie ? ma bicyclette ?... Ah, vous auriez autrement ri, godé, là, net fol !
- Maintenant faut un autre genre de rire...

Il est donc nécessaire, à mon avis, de lire « Jésus » en négatif dans ce « Jasus », d'autant plus que, n'omettons pas de le remarquer, il y a une capitale à ce mot, ce qui en fait un nom propre.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse détaillée, LPH !!

Comment: Oui, bravo pour cette réponse.Il y a bien un jeu de mot macabre dans ce texte.

Comment: @pirela Parmi les jeux de mots ce serait un [calembour](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_mots#Types) (« Demandez nos exquis mots ! »).

Answer (score 2):

Je connais mal l'auteur, son oeuvre, ses références toponymiques et culturelles et son style et il me faudrait bien plus qu'une page pour m'y habituer. Mais si on prend pour acquis que l'auteur référe à *Jésus*, l'emploi, s'il était argotique (je trouve raisonnable de croire qu'il puisse l'être), serait plutôt sans équivoque ([1](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/18024/18024-h/18024-h.htm#J_K), [2](https://archive.org/details/DictionnaireDargot/page/n83/mode/2up), [3](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedela00delvuoft/page/242/mode/2up), [4](https://archive.org/details/dictionnaireargo00deleuoft/page/156/mode/2up), [5](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedarg00virmuoft/page/152/mode/2up)). On a des idées de petit enfant mignon (comme dans *petit Jésus*) et d'innocence (la phrase contient d'ailleurs ce mot ?) et on arrive dans certains milieux à l'*allusion à l'homosexualité*, valeur qu'on trouve dans le titre d'une oeuvre comme [*Jésus-la-caille*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A9sus-la-Caille) (DHLF). On pourrait comparer le contexte d'emploi du mot avec d'autres emplois dans l'oeuvre de l'auteur pour voir...

Comment: Bien plus vraisemblable que les cris de la langouste qu'on écartèle !

Comment: Relisez, il n'y a pas de cri dans le texte.  Ensuite une langouste se découpe vivante avant cuisson, on reste bien dans l'horreur. S'il n'y a pas de double lecture Jésus/Jasus vous pensez  que Céline ait fait involontairement une faute d'orthographe ? Impensable.

Comment: @pirela Bien sûr qu'il y a des cris: les Jasus *déchirent l'air de leur cris.* Cette théorie de la langouste me semble absurde. Céline n'en est pas à une liberté avec l'orthographe ou à un hapax près. Il ne faut pas prendre Céline au pied de la lettre (c'est le cas de le dire). C'est peut-être simplement une représentation phonétique de l'accent parisien de l'époque. Arletty aurait sûrement prononcé *Jaésus, Jaésus, est-ce que j'ai une gueule de Jaésus...*

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa Malheureusement, il n'y a pas d'explication dans l'édition de la Pléiade.